# T-SQL, Ordering conundrum

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL ordering conundrum which I'm rattling around with - any guidance would be great.

I have a dataset which I'm looking to conditionally based on values (which are actually dateDiff(s). The current order by is : difStartSecs, difExpireSecs

```
Record  difStartSecs difExpireSecs
1       -1521865     1242935
2       -81865       4535
3       -71065       15335
4       -63865       22535 
5       -17065       69335
6       -6265        80135
7       -5365        5435
8       4535         90935
9       5435         16235
```

What I'm looking to do is order by difStartSecs (longest since start first) - BUT - also to take into consideration difExpireSec value at the same time.

In this example, the desired end result would be : 2,7,3,4,5,6,1,8,9

Because even though record one is the oldest, it also has the longest yet to run.

Similarly, record 7, may be the newest, but is the 2nd earliest to finish.

Records 8 & 9 and onwards will always be at the end as they have yet to 'start'

I hope I've explained that correctly ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and results, I end up on the following:

```
order by
     case when difStartSecs<0 then 1 else 2 end asc
    ,case when difStartSecs<0 then difExpireSecs else difStartSecs end asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order by an expression:

```
Select * 
from myTable
order by case when difStartSecs <= 0 then -1 else 1 end, difExpireSecs;
```

Comment: `order by sign(difStartSecs), difExpireSecs` seems more straightforward

Comment: @Charlieface nice one

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more efficient version would use a `union all`. This assumes you have a clustered index over `difStartSecs` (or a non-clustered one including all those columns)

```sql
SELECT
  Record,
  difStartSecs,
  difExpireSecs
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS ordering
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE difStartSecs < 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 2
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE difStartSecs >= 0
) t
ORDER BY Ordering, difExpireSecs;
```